# How do I use a line break in the footer title of a UITableView?

Tags: ios, uitableview, cocoa-touch

I provide a footer title for my table view like this:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForFooterInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    return "DEVELOPED BY COMPANY NAME\nIN COMPANY LOCATION"
}
```

When I run my code, only "DEVELOPED BY COMPANY NAME" shows up in the footer and the text beyond the line break is nowhere to be seen. How would I go about making sure that all of the text is seen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default footer view is a label with 1 line of text.

If you want a label with multiple lines you’ll have to create a view and return it in the function `viewForFooterInSection`.

You will also need to implement the function `heightForFooterInSection` to give the label the correct height. (Thanks rmaddy)

Comment: And you'll also need to implement `heightForFooterInSection`.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, just implemented it however and I am still not seeing the text beyond the line break.

Comment: @James did you make sure to set `label.numberOfLines = 2`?

Comment: @Fogmeister yes I did, just realized I had my height set wrong. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

If it is conform to your design you can change to a grouped table style in Interface Builder.

1. In storyboard - select your viewController - Select the table
2. Select the "Style" property in interface-builder
3. Select "Grouped"

Grouped Style provides per default a multiline Footer. Just override `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForFooterInSection section: Int) -> String?`

Thats it. No need for an extra view or providing the height.